# split php string by colon using split

Tags: php

I wanted to do something like this:

```
list($hour, $minute) = split("/:/", $departure_time);
```

however it says split() is deprecated why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `split()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split` belongs to the `ereg` class functions, which have been superseded by [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) and [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split).

You should be using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) anyway, since you only have a static string, not an actual matching pattern with variable placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode()` instead of `split()`.

like this:

```
$array = explode(':', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use explode instead

```
$arr=explode("/:/", $departure_time);
```